# How to implement jquery ajax tabs without visible href in tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I've succesfully implemented an ajax tab system for my page and its working properly.

The issue i'm facing is that the url of the the href is visible when a user hovers over tab and if he right clicks and opens in new tab, the included php file is opened.

I want to hide the urls of my tab hrefs to be hidden and also these files should not be able to execute when accessed directly. Can any of the gurus help

my code is as below:

```
<div class="col-md-12">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#internal" data-toggle="tabajax">Internal Readings</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/1.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#qr" class="media_node span" id="qr_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Results</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/2.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#kfr" class="media_node span" id="kfr_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Ratios</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/3.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#pl" class="media_node span" id="pl_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">PL</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/4.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#bs" class="media_node span" id="bl_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Balance</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/5.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#cf" class="media_node span" id="cf_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Flow</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/8.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#mf" class="media_node span" id="mf_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Holdings</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/9.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#info" class="media_node span" id="info_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Info</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="wait" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:30px;left:50%;padding:2px;margin-top:100px;">
        <img src="./images/loading_m.gif" width="64" height="64" /><br>Loading..
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="internal">

        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <canvas  id="Charts"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="qr">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="kfr">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="pl">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bs">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cf">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="mf">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="info">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js in the page is as below

```
<script>
jQuery('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
var $this = jQuery(this),
    loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
    targ = $this.attr('data-target');

jQuery.get(loadurl, function(data) {

    jQuery(targ).html(data);
});

$this.tab('show');
return false;
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){
jQuery("#wait").css("display", "inline");
});
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
jQuery("#wait").css("display", "none");
});
});
</script>
```

For disabling direct access to file I tried using:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
// redirect them to your desired location 
header('location:../index.php'); 
exit; 
}
```

But as per SO its not effective, also tried tracedebug, but it did not allow the tabs to be loaded, so looking other means.

```js
jQuery('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = jQuery(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');
 
    jQuery.get(loadurl, function(data) {
  
        jQuery(targ).html(data);
    });
 
    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
 });
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        jQuery("#wait").css("display", "inline");
    });
    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        jQuery("#wait").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="#internal" data-toggle="tabajax">Tab1</a>
  </li>
  
  <li>
   <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/1.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#qr" class="media_node span" id="qr_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Tab2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/2.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#kfr" class="media_node span" id="kfr_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Tab3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/3.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#pl" class="media_node span" id="pl_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Tab4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/4.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#bs" class="media_node span" id="bl_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Tab5</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/5.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#cf" class="media_node span" id="cf_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Tab6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/8.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#mf" class="media_node span" id="mf_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Tab7</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'q2/9.php?var='.$var ?>" data-target="#info" class="media_node span" id="info_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Tab8</a>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content responsive">
  <div id="wait" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:30px;left:50%;padding:2px;margin-top:100px;">
   <img src="./images/loading_m.gif" width="64" height="64" /><br>Loading..
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="internal">
   
   <div class="row">
    <div>
     <canvas  id="Charts"></canvas>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab-pane" id="qr">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="kfr">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="pl">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="bs">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="cf">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="mf">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="info">
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: for disabling direct access to file i tried using: if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    // redirect them to your desired location
    header('location:../index.php');
    exit;
 } But as per SO its not effective, also tried tracedebug, but it did not allow the tabs to be loaded, so looking other means

Comment: You could use another data attribute, and make href just "#". For example data-href

Comment: As far as I understood, the only reason you are having problems is beacause of the default behaviour of the attribute href. You are using the href just to store the url (you are retrieving the url with JQuery and returning false, effectively preventing the default behaviour, which doesn't happen when opening in new tab). Just change the html and js from href to data-href (and you may also add a href="#")

Comment: Thanks gerad, i managed hide the url, i used an addtional tag data attribute with the full href link and changed href=#, Thanks a lot. Can you also please guide how can i prevent direct access to the files.

Comment: That I cannot help with.sorry!